# Add extra params to user from devise in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I want to add a property name in the user model. I ran the migration command to add the column to the database and that worked. Adding the property to user itself worked as well but it isn't saved in the db.

How can I add the property "name" to the required params of the `sign_up` and `account_update` of RegistrationController?

This is my user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  attr_accessor :name
end
```

I tried adding the required params to the methodes like this in the `RegistrationController`

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name,:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
  end
end
```

In the routings i added the line

`devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations' }`

But the name of the user still isn't saved in the database.

Comment: it's created by scaffolding or manually?

Comment: the devise was from scaffolding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your `ApplicationController` to configure `signup` `signin` & `account_update` params.

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:name,:email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:login, :username, :email, :password, :remember_me) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:name, :username, :anonymous, :email, :password, :password_confirmation,:reset_password_token) }
end
```

And also add `before_filter` to `ApplicationController` like :

```
before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
```

Comment: Seemed to work only after i removed the property i had added in my user model.. But it did work so thx!

Answer (score 0):

Please check [Devise Parameter Sanitization](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters)

You can try this:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

 def sign_up_params
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up).push(:name)
 end

 def account_update_params
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update).push(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
 end
end
```

Comment: I get this error `No sanitizer provided for user`.

Comment: In this answer try changing arguments for `for` from `:user` to `:sign_up` and `:account_update`.

Comment: @sajan thanks for pointing that out. I have edited the answer.